# PDO in PHP returns error which not happens in MySQL console

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code:

```
$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tagged_cards WHERE card_tags LIKE '%test%';");
$cards_data = $stmt->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I execute it, I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'card_tags' in 'where clause'
```

However, when I log into a database server and use MySQL console (or MySQL Workbench) for exactly the same query, it successfully executes with results as expected.

The table contains the mentioned column.

I already eliminated factors like typos, connecting by mistake to other database or possible caching. What can cause an error like this?

Comment: Do you have more than one copy of the database? Like another database with similar-but-different tables? It looks to me that whatever database PDO is using has a different version of the table than the database you use in console.

Comment: Ah, I see you say that you've eliminated that possibility... but have you? Try this: in your php code, put a database prefix on the table name, like this: `SELECT * FROM myDatabaseName.tagged_cards ...` -- report results.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear and unambiguous: there is no such column in the table. So, you have to connect a database where such field exists.

Comment: Note: if you do have a field with that name check for case sensitivity

Answer (score 0):

The ERROR clearly states that `card_tags` does not exist in `tagged_cards` table in your database.

Run this query to show column names in `tagged_cards` table. Ensure `$db` is connected to same database as in question.

```
$stmt = $db->query("DESCRIBE tagged_cards");
$columnNames = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
print_r($columnNames);
```

The following table seems to show that there are 2 id fields which should be impossible.

[image: table]

The reason for this is #2 has a leading space

[image: field input]

The above query returns `Array ([0] => id [1] => id )` in browser, so check for leading spaces if table name seems correct.